# Birt Report Engine. Error evaluating Javascript expression

Tags: javascript, java, web-applications, reporting, birt

After following this [Integrating the BIRT Viewer with a custom Java Platform, Enterprise Edition web application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-birt-viewer-java-webapps/index.html#Problembackground) to integrate birt reporting with my web application, I get the following error when am running the report viewer.

```
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.app.birt.util.JSONParser] is not a function, it is object. (/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"]#6)
 Script source: /report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"], line: 0, text:
__bm_OPEN()
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.JSMethodRunner.runScript(JSMethodRunner.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DtEScriptExecutor.handleJS(DtEScriptExecutor.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.DataSourceScriptExecutor.handleJS(DataSourceScriptExecutor.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.script.internal.ScriptDataSourceScriptExecutor.handleOpen(ScriptDataSourceScriptExecutor.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ScriptDataSourceRuntime.open(ScriptDataSourceRuntime.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ScriptDataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(ScriptDataSourceRuntime.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1939)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.resumeLayout(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLInlineStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLInlineStackingLM.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLStackingLM.layoutChildren(HTMLStackingLM.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLTableLM.layoutChildren(HTMLTableLM.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLAbstractLM.layout(HTMLAbstractLM.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runReport(ReportEngineService.java:1325)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtRunReportActionHandler.__execute(BirtRunReportActionHandler.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageActionHandler.__checkDocumentExists(BirtGetPageActionHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.prepareParameters(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractGetPageActionHandler.__execute(AbstractGetPageActionHandler.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPage(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:151)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.app.birt.util.JSONParser] is not a function, it is object. (/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"]#6)
 Script source: /report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"], line: 0, text:
__bm_OPEN()
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException.wrap(DataException.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.ScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(ScriptEvalUtil.java:996)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.JSMethodRunner.runScript(JSMethodRunner.java:138)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.core.exception.CoreException: Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.app.birt.util.JSONParser] is not a function, it is object. (/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"]#6)
 Script source: /report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"], line: 0, text:
__bm_OPEN()
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.wrapRhinoException(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.ScriptEvalUtil.evaluateJSAsExpr(ScriptEvalUtil.java:992)
    ... 110 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.app.birt.util.JSONParser] is not a function, it is object. (/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"]#6)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3654)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3632)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3660)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3679)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3734)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:3722)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.newObject(ScriptRuntime.java:2324)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4._c1(/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"]:6)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c4.call(/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"])
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:108)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c5._c0(/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"]:0)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c5.call(/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"])
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:398)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3065)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c5.call(/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"])
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c5.exec(/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="57"]/method[@name="open"])
    at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.JavascriptEvalUtil.evaluateRawScript(JavascriptEvalUtil.java:95)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are using the library the wrong way (note: I don't know this class or package): The error message says that com.app.birt.util.JSONParser is a Java package, but you are calling it as a function. But the error messages of the Rhinoscript engine are sometimes confusing - maybe the JAR containing com.app.birt.util.JSONParser is not included in the ClassPath at runtime?

Comment: Thanks. You are right, i got it all wrong, I was using it in test application and it was working, and the JsonParser class was located in the  com.app.birt.util package. Then moved to another project and the package name change.